# drawing on window using gtk 2.0

Tags: c, interface, gtk, drawing, gtk2

I have a program using pthreads. I want add an interface using gtk2.0, but have a problem with drawing on window. When I call `g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "configure_event",G_CALLBACK(draw_things), NULL);`
lines which I draw appear and at once disappear. If I move a window calling function 
`gtk_window_move (GTK_WINDOW(widget), 10,10);`
or by means of a mouse, lines appear. If I call `g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "expose_event", G_CALLBACK(draw_things), NULL);` my lines are displayed correctly, but buttons and labels are not displayed. My code looks like this:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        pthread_t tr1;
        pthread_t tr2;
        pthread_t *trs;
        int rc = 0;
        type j;
        int16_t *id;
        type Stop_Point;

        GtkWidget *window;
        GtkWidget *button;
        GtkWidget *table;
        GtkWidget *drawing_area;

        g_thread_init (NULL);
        gdk_threads_init ();
        gdk_threads_enter ();
        gtk_init (&argc, &argv);        

        window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
        gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, width/1.6, height/1.33);
        gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), -1);

        gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
        g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "delete_event", G_CALLBACK (delete_event), NULL);
        gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 2);
        table = gtk_table_new ( width/1.6, height/1.33, TRUE);
        gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), table);

        button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("next >>");
        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), button, 1110, 1190, 750, 790);
        gtk_widget_show (button);

        button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("<< prev");
        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), button, 1020, 1100 , 750, 790);
        gtk_widget_show (button);

        rc = pthread_create(&tr1, NULL, tr1_func, &id);
        rc = pthread_create(&Generator, NULL, tr2_func, &Stop_Point);
        trs = (pthread_t*)malloc(Num * sizeof(pthread_t));
        for(j = 0; j < Num; j++) {
             rc = pthread_create(trs + j, NULL, trs_func, id + j);
        }

//      g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "configure-event", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(draw_things), NULL);
        g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "expose_event", G_CALLBACK(draw_things), NULL);
        gtk_widget_show_all (window);
        gtk_main ();

        gdk_threads_leave ();

        return 0;
}
```

Fnction for drawing looks like this

```
gboolean draw_things(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer data) {

    GdkGC *gc;

    gc=gdk_gc_new(GDK_DRAWABLE(widget->window));
    gdk_gc_set_line_attributes(gc, 5, GDK_LINE_SOLID, GDK_CAP_ROUND, GDK_JOIN_ROUND);
    gdk_draw_line(GDK_DRAWABLE(widget->window), gc, 5, 35, 1200, 35);
    gdk_draw_line(GDK_DRAWABLE(widget->window), gc, 1170, 45, 1200, 35);
    gdk_draw_line(GDK_DRAWABLE(widget->window), gc, 1170, 25 , 1200, 35);
//    gtk_window_move (GTK_WINDOW(widget), 1,1);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Any help is welcomed, because now I use "configure_event" and call `gtk_window_move (GTK_WINDOW(widget), 0,0);` every time when I need to draw the picture.

Comment: Throw away that GdkGC stuff and use cairo, it's available, even on GTK 2.

Comment: You should be drawing to your GtkDrawingArea I believe. Also be careful, threads and GUI don't mix. All your widget drawing should take place in the main thread.